# Unable to Add Text File to Azure DevOps Repo using RestApi - File containing '\'

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add a file "AssemblyInfo.cs" which contain a '' as part of the text.

[image]
When trying to use the [RestAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#add-a-text-file) to do it i get Error 400

[image]

After Removing the Char RestApi pass
[image]

i am using the following code to convert the text to Json - Powershell based

```
function GetJSContentCS {
    param (
        $filepath
    )
    $read = (Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -RAW -Path $filepath) -replace "(?s)`r`n\s*$"
    $jscontent=''
    foreach ($item in $read) {
        $jsitem = $item+'\n'
        $jsitem = $jsitem.replace('"','\"')
        $jscontent += $jsitem
    }
    return $jscontent
}
GetJSContentCS -filepath 'C:\temp\AssemblyInfo (2).cs'
```

Any Advise Would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is missing a `\` character after `c:` in the converted Json.

By running the PowerShell the converted Json is :

`[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @\"c:\appsLogging.xml\", Watch = true)]\n`

However, the correct Json should like this:

`[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @\"c:\\appsLogging.xml\", Watch = true)]`

Please try the following script to convert the text to Json:

```
function GetJSContentCS {
    param (
        $filepath
    )
    $read = (Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -RAW -Path $filepath) -replace "(?s)`r`n\s*$"
    cls
    Write-Host $read 
    $jscontent=''
    foreach ($item in $read) {
        $jsitem = $item.replace('"','\"')
        $jsitem = $jsitem.replace(':\',':\\')
        $jscontent += $jsitem
    }
    return $jscontent
}
GetJSContentCS -filepath 'C:\temp\AssemblyInfo.cs'
```

**UPDATE:**

Sample PowerShell script for your reference to call the [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#add-a-text-file) REST API to add a file :

```
Param(
[string]$orgurl = “https://dev.azure.com/{organization}",
[string]$project = “ProjectName”,
[string]$repoid = “166d743e-623a-4bdd-923b-6af25ebfdf9a”,
[string]$oldObjectId = “cbfc5c415de65cf40bcc9509d8ee286e7c990a56”, #Previous commit ID
[string]$user = “”,
[string]$token = “PAT”
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get contents from the AssemblyInfo.cs file and convert to the correct Json. 

function GetJSContentCS {
    param (
        $filepath
    )
    $read = (Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -RAW -Path $filepath) -replace "(?s)`r`n\s*$"
    cls
    Write-Host $read 
    $jscontent=''
    foreach ($item in $read) {
        $jsitem = $item.replace('"','\"')
        $jsitem = $jsitem.replace(':\',':\\')
        $jscontent += $jsitem
    }
    return $jscontent
}
GetJSContentCS -filepath 'C:\temp\AssemblyInfo.cs'


#Create Json body
 
function CreateJsonBody
{
 
    $value = @"
    {
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "$oldObjectId"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added a AssemblyInfo3.cs file.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "add",
          "item": {
            "path": "/AssemblyInfo3.cs"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "$jscontent",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"@
 
return $value
}
 
$json = CreateJsonBody

#Add files - Push commint to repository
$Url = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repoid/pushes?api-version=7.1-preview.2"   
$push = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $json -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} 
$push
```

[image]

Comment: i dont need \n at the end of the line ?

Comment: @galsi `\n` is not needed, please see the updated answer.